# MIT App Inventor 2 Creating Components With Procedures

Tags: android, block, app-inventor

I'm exploring MIT App Inventor to use for some students I am working with, and I'm trying to get an idea of the limitations. One question I can't seem to find an answer to is: can you create new components (ie. buttons, horizontalArrangements, etc.) using a procedure in the blocks section. I'm thinking the answer is no, but I just want confirmation that I'm not missing something.

Thanks for your help! 
~Zoltana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes correct you cann't create new components.

Few other limitations are:

- Limited set of components
- Limited device accessibility options
- To interact with Web, have to use their APIs but you can not use other protocols or APIs
- Limited no# of screens in one App ( if I recall correctly In my recent App it was 30 screens)

To create new components or Layout, try to use the existing ones and play with visibility options to hide/show , increase/decrease width/height etc...on demand.

Comment: Thanks for listing the limitations! I really appreciate it. I seem to be having trouble with the app crashing even after just 5 screens are added. Seems like it is a good solution for just the very basics.

Comment: @zoltana if your app is crashing after 5 screens, let me assume you do not switch screens correctly, see the recommended  [manager screen method](https://puravidaapps.com/manager.php). Btw. who needs 30 screens? If you really think, you need 30 screens, you should read this [Building apps with many screens](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/manyscreens.html)...

Comment: @zoltana, if your App is crashing then if you like to share the project then I may help the students. Its good to help students...they are our future....you can upload on any cloud service and drop url here. thanks

Answer (score 1):

It cannot.

An alternative is to create extensions that will allow you to create dynamic components. These extensions can be imported into App Inventor and then used.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't create new components during runtime of the app with **App Inventor**.

But you can prepare as much components  (for example buttons) as you think you will need and hide them. Then as soon you need them, just set their visibility to true.

Answer (score 0):

I was taught my AP Computer Science Principles course last year using MIT App Inventor 2. I can say that the app is limited if you are planning to create a full-fledged application that handles more than a few Mb of RAM at a time.

You cannot add Components during the run time of the program due to the size limitations of App Inventor.

As I recall, apps created in App Inventor cannot exceed 5Mb of storage, and that's why you cannot add components during run time.

App Inventor is, however, a good way to teach beginning programming students(I assume that's who your targeted audience is) the thought process behind programming. Such as If...Then statements and various types of Loops, as well as how to think in terms of programming.